# array to xml or xspf make xspf file for embed vlc lugin playlist

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xspf

i am trying input check box list current folder .mp3 get using gob function glob_grace list the audio files using check box then

get array check box values make xspf file using php

i write code all for array to xml

but small error please anyone tell me what error and the error where occurred !

```
<?php   
foreach (glob("*.{mp3,mp4}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    $values = $filename ;
    echo "<form action='p.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' value='$values'>$values <hr>";    

}
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
    echo "</form>";

?>
```

it will go to next page below

```
<?php
        $g = $_POST['foo'];
       $cnt = count($g);
        //function definition to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml($array, &$xml_user_info) {
    for ($i=0 ; $i < $cnt ;$i++)
    {
        $track = $xml_user_info->addChild('track');
        $track->addChild("location",$array[$i]);
     }                                       

}

//creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_user_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><trackList></trackList>");

//function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($g,$xml_user_info);

//saving generated xml file
$xml_file = $xml_user_info->asXML('users.xspf');

//success and error message based on xml creation
if($xml_file){
    echo 'XML file have been generated successfully.';
}else{
    echo 'XML file generation error.';
}
?>
```

please give me answer solution working code

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `glob("*.{mp3,mp4}", GLOB_BRACE)` returns an array with more than 1 item, you are generating the `<form action='p.php' method='POST'>` tag multiple times.

Maybe you could move the form declaration to outside of the `foreach`.

If I submit the form and I load the *p.php*, I get this Notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: cnt

You are using `$cnt = count($g);` to count the items, but you could also  pass this `$g` and count its items inside the `function array_to_xml`.

I think that if you want to get the value from `$_POST['foo']`, you should first check if it is a POST and then check if the `$_POST['foo']` is set.

Maybe this setup can help you:

```
<?php

//function definition to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml($array, &$xml_user_info)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $track = $xml_user_info->addChild('track');
        $track->addChild("location", $array[$i]);
    }
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['foo'])) {
        $g = $_POST['foo'];

        //creating object of SimpleXMLElement
        $xml_user_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><trackList></trackList>");

        //function call to convert array to xml
        array_to_xml($g, $xml_user_info);

        //saving generated xml file
        $xml_file = $xml_user_info->asXML('users.xspf');

        //success and error message based on xml creation
        if ($xml_file) {
            echo 'XML file have been generated successfully.';
        } else {
            echo 'XML file generation error.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro the forth bird

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><playlist></playlist>');
$trackList = $xml->addChild('trackList');
foreach ($_POST['files'] as $video) {
    $track = $trackList->addChild('track');
    $track->addChild('location', 'file://'.$tmp_dir.'/'.$video['path']);
    $track->addChild('title', $video['name']);
}
file_put_contents('playlist.xspf',$xml->asXML());
```